# Windows 11 randomly resize to like 1/8 of screen size and placed in top left corner randomly

Tags: resolution, windows-11, 4k-resolution, bug

I've been experiencing some strangeness. On the latest udpate of windows 11. For some reason, when I come back to my computer after a few minutes - randomly - all of my windows will have resized to maybe 1/8 of the normal resolution (regardless if maximized previously or not) and have been placed in the top left of the screen.

I have start11 and stardock fences installed. Also WinAeroTweaks.

I've tried setting the registry settings you'll find on similar google searches to all be 4k. Didn't work.

I've tried an edid 4k hdmi dummy plug. Didn't work.

No matter what, TOTALLY RANDOMLY, my pc resets the resolution to lke 400x560 or somethign ridiculously small and I have to grab ALL my windows that were open to resize them or maximise them. It's bloody annoying and NOTHING is working. Any help would be a total godsend but I'm pulling my hair resizing windows all the time.

Something also strange but probably related - the recycle randomly moves one icon to the right or downward. Seems like windows is changing my resolution for some reason.

For more context, I use an LG C1 and a program called lgtvCompanion that uses WOL to wake up the tv when the computer wakes up and can turn the the tv off after a set amount of idle time, or whenever your screensaver or monitor turn off activates

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried going into Windows Settings and changed the resolution under the display tab. If that doesn't work remove all the tweaks and programs you have installed that affect display scaling like Start11, Stardock, winaerotweaks and just use 1 standard connection to the monitor without any adapters (also could you provide the type of connection you are using eg HDMI, DVI, DP or VGA). If that doesn't work, try using another machine with the monitor and post if it is the monitor or laptop.

Comment: I have tried all those things already. No idea why it's happening.